# Ionic Ios app error : Device won't connect to server

Tags: ios, cordova, debugging, ionic-framework

Hi I'm currently creating a mobile app using Ionic, I've tested my app on Android & Ios from the web browser and it works fine, I've tested it on Android devices and it works fine but now when I'm testing it on an Iphone SE using Xcode it doesn't connect to my database.

I've tried using the debug tools on safari and looking at the console and debugger but I don't get much info. See below:

[image]

The start of the app works fine(SplashScreen & initial page) but when I try to log in my app doesn't seem to do anything. I've checked the logs from the server where my database is running also and it looks like the app isn't calling the method to make a request to the DB.

Do I have to allow web services or anything when it comes to testing on IOS devices?

Also: This is the error from the console on Xcode :

> "ERROR: Plugin 'Device' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml."

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone who might come across this, I fixed this by deleting my node modules :

```
 rm -rf node_modules/ platforms/ios
```

Then switching my version of "cordova-ios" to "4.4.0" inside my package.json folder:

```
"cordova-ios": "4.4.0"
```

Followed by re-installing my node modules:

```
 npm i
```

And finally just running the command to build for ios again:

```
 ionic cordova build ios
```